# how can i make my macro toggle a sheets visibility/hide?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

i have the following code that i want to toggle a sheet being visible or being hidden:

```
Sub toggle()
If Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible = True Then
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Else
    Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible
End If
End Sub
```

but it error's out on the else sheets visible statement. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error message? why do you use different object for `If` and `ElseIf`?

Comment: changed the elseif statement to an else. now it errors out on the sheets visible statement. the sheets visible should be a good command. what is wrong with the macro?

Comment: getting a "run time error 1004, visible method of worksheet class failed.

Comment: why do you use `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible` once and `Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible` the other times?? are those the same? your post currently doesn't seem to be useful for anybody else looking for help.

Comment: You didn't assign the value `Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible ` - you need to have `= true` or `= false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically you put a `=True` where it's not needed and forgot it where it *is* needed.

```
Sub toggle()
    If Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible Then
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
    Else: Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see in the [visible method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197786.aspx), it evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This is why you don't need it after `if` but is also why you need it after `Else:`

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
Sub toggle()
If Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible = True Then
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
Else
    Sheets("Navigation (2)").Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```